# Why is nodeJS returning different 'req.session'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-api, passport.js

I am trying to verify that a user who has logged in using **Google API** is successfully logged in. In my **React App** I fetch to 'http://localhost:3001/auth/google/check' route to get this.

***The fetch in my React application:***

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/google/check', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        if(data === 'LOGIN_SUCCESS') {    
            const {login, changePage} = this.props;
            login('LOGIN_SUCCESS');
            changePage('GO_TO_PROFILE_PAGE');
        }
    })
```

***In my server I'm using passportJS to authenticate:***

```
app.get('/auth/google/check', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.status(200).json('LOGIN_SUCCESS');
    }
    else {
        res.status(400).json('Login failed.');
    }
})
```

On my app page('http://localhost:3000') when I fetch, I receive status 400, 'Login failed' message and on the server side the **'req.session.passport'** is undefined, but, when I open a new tab and put the url 'http://localhost:3001/auth/google/check' it returns 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' and on my server side I have **'req.session.passport.user'** successfully serialized. Why am I receiving different **'req.session'**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to configure `fetch` to pass the cookie on the request.

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/google/check', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
        credentials: 'include'
    })
```

Reference: https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies